# decimal separator in woocommerce to be a comma

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a woocommerce shop in which I have set up my prices (in settings) to have the decimal separator to be a comma instead of a dot (EURO system).
The problem is in the code I need to add. There is this part:

```
$price_excl_vat = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); // Unit price excluding VAT
```

and this

```
<?php echo $items_string;
```

where it returns the prices with a dot.

Any tips on how to make it give the prices with a comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `number_format( $price_excl_vat, 2, ',', ' ' );` to format your price with the decimal separator set as comma.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

You could also use the woocommerce function `wc_price( $price_excl_vat, array( 'decimal_separator' => ',' ) );`. This function wil return a formatted price with a currency symbol and the decimal separator set as comma.

http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_price/

Comment: Thank you. I played around with the second option before asking but I couldn't get exactly what I wanted. The first one worked like a charm.